# Postfix couldn't send mail on Ubuntu VPS server, network unreachable/connection timeout

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I have a problem with postfix. When I am trying to send some mail from commandline, I get:

```
Feb 14 12:44:35 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 14 12:45:05 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.27]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 12:45:05 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 14 12:45:35 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Feb 14 12:45:35 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Feb 14 12:45:35 some-server postfix/smtp[1022]: D23CB41F3B: to=<kail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=60, delays=0.03/0/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

When I try to telnet to smtp.gmail.com:25:

```
 ~$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 64.233.164.108...
```

And it hangs.

Any idea, why it is not working? What should I check? Firewall 25 port (also 465/587) is opened, main.cf config:

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = some-server.e24cloud.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = some-server.domain, some-server.e24cloud.com, localhost.e24cloud.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Edit:

ifconfig and ufw settings:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:9b:81:8a  
          inet addr:12.34.56.78  Bcast:255.255.248.0  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe9b:818a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1460047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1482450 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:224872395 (224.8 MB)  TX bytes:5739336340 (5.7 GB)

ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
115/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
14956                      ALLOW       Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere
12257/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
Bind9                      ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Secure              ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
1022/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
12257                      ALLOW       Anywhere
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
9418/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
115/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
14956 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
12257/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Bind9 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Secure (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1022/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
12257 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9418/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: You have problems with your network settings (ipv4, ipv6, gateway, dns, firewalling) and, due to them, postfix is unable to connect to external SMTP servers (note: this might be a "feature", not a " bug", depending on you provider VPS offering). Please tell us more details about your nerworking configuration.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli any other options you need? I still have no idea how to fix this...interfaces is on dhcp, could that be the issue?

Comment: I bet the you've mistakenly reported a WRONG broadcast address in your network configuration. Please check it twice, as well as the netmask (that even if it sounds correct, it looks unusual, for an Internet hosted server). Check them, and let us know.

Comment: How could I check correct broadcast? Netmask - probably is correct. Even if it looks unusual, similar (broadcast and mask the same - 255.255.255.0) on other server works ok.

edit: as far I can check, if I try mail addresses with normal 80 port via telnet, it's connecting. It's just on port 25 (or 587, whish also is active and "secured" by postfix).